# Imported file need to remove first to numbers for match

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to get a result in SQL, where the Table1.Nr <> Table2.Nr. I have inner joined them. But here is the thing, I imported the data to Table2 and I want to match it with the data in table1 to see which ones are correct and which ones are incorrect.

Here is the thing, from the import file the Nr is 43210123 example but I need to have the first two numbers removed which mean 210123. How do I do this? Left doenst work really, since it's 3600 rows aprox.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using **[Substring](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748.aspx)**

```
substring(column_name,3,len(column_name)-2)
```

In your case

```
Table1.Nr<>substring(Table2.Nr,3,len(Table2.Nr)-2)
```

Comment: Thank you! That solved my problems and answered my question :)